# Access denied to all profiles of a certain type

Tags: 8, users, migrations

I am migrating from D7 to D8. I've had success with everything but the profiles from D7's profile2 module.

Four profile types have to be migrated. One of them is being migrated without issue: I can view and edit them. The other three, however, are giving me "Access Denied" errors when I try to view them. There is no difference in the parameters for the individual profile type migrations, aside from the names of the fields and the names of the profiles themselves.

When I view the list of profiles at `admin/people/profiles`, only one type of profile as an option to edit it. The others just have a button that says "Devel."

My user has permission to view, edit, and create profiles of all types, so it does not appear to be a permissions issue. I know for a fact that the data is being migrated, because I can see it in the MySQL DB. I have also cleared the cache, updated the db, and rebuilt the permissions.

I'm stumped, and I really need to have access to those profiles.

- Drupal Version: 8.9.6
- PHP Version 7.3.22
- MariaDB Version: 5.5.5-10.4.14

Incidentally, using the patch at https://www.drupal.org/project/profile/issues/2957256 made the migration of profiles possible in the first place.

Comment: Compare the db profile tables I guess. See if the ones with issue has something missing compared to the working one.

Comment: Nothing is missing compared to the working one.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what's happening now. During migration, empty profiles were made for users who did not have profiles on the origin site. That is why access is denied: there isn't anything to access. That message really should be "a profile doesn't exist yet," or something like that. I can see the existing profiles without any issue.